# JMapViewer OSM map cannot be dragged

Tags: java, swing, openstreetmap, jmapviewer

I am trying to figure out which mapping tools work best for my java swing based OSM map. Earlier I made a functioning map on the basis of [MapPanel](http://mappanel.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mappanel/com.roots.map/src/com/roots/map/MapPanel.java?revision=37&view=markup). Later I could almost clone the application and merely replace MapPanel with [JMapViewer](http://www.koders.com/java/fidC94F88CBDBF7178364503105DBA9941391242FC3.aspx?s=TileMap) to get this working as well. I prefer the latter as it has the functionality of putting markers and polygons on the map. The drawback however is that for some reason I cannot drag the map with the mouse. In the package of JMapViewer there is a Demo class which displays the same behaviour. How can I make the OSM map draggable within JMapViewer?

Edit: This code will draw a map that can be displayed in a panel *and* make the map draggable by adding a `mapController` and `setMovementMouseButton()`.

```
private JMapViewer drawOpenStreetMap(double lon, double lat, int zoom) {
    mapViewer = new JMapViewer();
    mapViewer.setZoom(zoom);
    mapViewer.setDisplayPositionByLatLon(lat, lon, zoom);
    mapViewer.repaint();
    DefaultMapController mapController = new DefaultMapController(mapViewer);
    mapController.setMovementMouseButton(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
    mapViewer.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(52, 5.5));
    return mapViewer;
}
```

Comment: The Demo class is pictured [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While running `Demo.java`, control-click or right-click on the map to pan the view. Use `setMovementMouseButton()` to control the behavior.

Comment: Excellent, that works! This code will draw a map that can be displayed in a panel AND make the map draggable by adding a mapController and setMovementMouseButton().

Comment: :      JMapViewer drawOpenStreetMap(double lon, double lat, int zoom) {
     mapViewer = new JMapViewer(); 
     mapViewer.setZoom(zoom); 
        mapViewer.setDisplayPositionByLatLon(lat, lon, zoom); 
        mapViewer.repaint();
 DefaultMapController mapController = new DefaultMapController(mapViewer);
  mapController.setMovementMouseButton(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
        mapViewer.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(52, 5.5));
     
        return mapViewer;
    }